# Error when installing Google assistant on Windows 10

Tags: installation, google-assistant-sdk

I followed [this page](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/) to install Google Assistant on my Windows 10 PC.
When I run this command:

`py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]`

I got error the following Error!  Please help!!!

```
Collecting pycparser (from CFFI>=1.0->sounddevice==0.3.7; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples])
  Using cached pycparser-2.18.tar.gz
Collecting protobuf>=3.3.0 (from grpcio>=1.3.5->google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples])
  Using cached protobuf-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples])
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples])
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.3.0->grpcio>=1.3.5->google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples])
Installing collected packages: certifi, urllib3, idna, chardet, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, cachetools, six, google-auth, click, google-auth-oauthlib, pycparser, CFFI, sounddevice, protobuf, grpcio, googleapis-common-protos, google-assistant-grpc, monotonic, tenacity, google-assistant-sdk
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\certifi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cmd` in admin mode by hitting the windows key, typing `cmd`, right clicking and click run as administrator.